# Java renameTo() function not moving file

Tags: java, file-io

I have the following Java code running in a media module:

```
File file = new File("/my/path/"+String.format("%02d", date)+"/"+streamAliasRef+".mp4");

        // Destination directory
        File dir = new File("/mnt/s3");

        // Move file to new directory
        boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(dir, file.getName()));
        if (!success) {
            getLogger().info("File failed to move to s3"+file.getName());
        }
        else {
            getLogger().info("File moved to s3 successfully"+ file.getName());
        }
```

For some reason I am consistently getting "File failed to move to s3"

I'm pretty new to Java, so forgive me if this is a simple problem. I know for a fact that both directories exist. One important note which may have something to do with it is I'm using Fuse to mount an S3 bucket to the filesystem.

Comment: The file could only be moved if the entire directory tree of the source and destination exists, could you confirm this?

Comment: Well the a new file is generated each time with a new StreamAliasRef, is there a way to confirm that File file actually grabbed a file?

Comment: You can use `File.isFile()`, `File.isDirectory()` and `File.exists()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java running on unix, renameTo only works if you are in the same file system.  So if you are moving across filesystems, you will need to copy and delete the original.  The unix mv command does this as well.  This is why mv is instant on the same filesystem, but takes forever across filesystems.  It detects the different filesystems and does a copy delete in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I use this method from Guava to move files around on Unix to work around this issue:
`public static void move(File from, File to) throws IOException {
  Preconditions.checkNotNull(to);
  Preconditions.checkArgument(!from.equals(to),
    "Source %s and destination %s must be different", from, to);
  if (!from.renameTo(to)) {
    copy(from, to);
    if (!from.delete()) {
      if (!to.delete()) {
         throw new IOException("Unable to delete " + to);
      }
      throw new IOException("Unable to delete " + from);
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you sure that

```
new File("/my/path/"+String.format("%02d", date)+"/"+streamAliasRef+".mp4")
```

really exists ? Could you check with `file.exists()` prior to trying to move it ?